# enchant_broker_init() performance issue

Tags: apache, google-chrome-extension, aspell, pspell

I have a web site which uses enchant enchant_broker_init().
I`m not sure why but enchant_broker_init() takes something like 19~ seconds to load the page.
Once I remove this function page loads right away.

anyone has an idea why this is? or how can I debug it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to install php enchant plugin.

APACHE
http://apache.mivzakim.net//httpd/binaries/win32/#warnings

PHP
http://windows.php.net/download/

ENABLE PHP ON APACHE
http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.apache2.php

Enchant will not work using WAMP. ( at least for it hasn't... ).

Afterwards add the following path

share\myspell\dicts

to your PHP directory.

should look like that.

C:\PHP\share\myspell\dicts

Put the dictionary files there.
.aff
.dic